# I cannot disable the cloudformation snippets/suggestions in VS Code

Tags: aws-cloudformation, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am trying to disable (an annoying) AWS Cloudformation suggestions/snippets because they are cluttering my suggestions:

[image: Cloudformation suggestions]

It seems impossible to find where these are coming from:

- I disabled the AWS Plugins, no help.
- Tried to find the snippets with "Insert snippet", but couldn't find anything to match.
- Tried to google on the keywords but couldn't get a match due to them being so generic.

Can someone tell me:

1. Where can I find the source of these suggestions/snippets?
2. How to disable them?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For anyone with the same confusion, I fixed it:

So I started looking in the `/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Code/User` folder and searched for "!GetAZs" and found that they are apparently "custom YAML" snippets located in `settings.json`. I removed them from the list. That fixed it. No idea where they came from, I think from some extension that does not remove them on uninstall.